# Toggle() or ClassList.toggle()

Tags: javascript, cumulative-layout-shift

My page has some problems with CLS. It could be because I'm hiding some elements with JS and here is my question:

For CLS optimization, is it better to use `.toggle()` or add `displayNoneClass` to all elements I want to hide and then use `.classList.toggle("displayNoneClass")`?

Comment: does not matter at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Depends on the current display property of the element which you are going to hide..
When the current element is `display:inline` and you used `display:none;` property to hide it, you need to restore that property. where as toggle() changes only in jQuery cache so it doesn't need to restore that property..

If you don't want to change the CSS property by using `!important` you can use adding class otherwise can go with `toggle()` .

Otherwise its all the same

Comment: Okey, thank You. I am hidding my modals as defaul. You think that .toggle() would work better for that?

Comment: You can hide bootstrap model with `$('#modal').modal('hide');`  To know more [Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals) . `$().hide()` is also the same